# ASP.Net MVC Web App can I / should I securely store 3rd party login details

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, authentication, basic-authentication

We have an ASP.Net Web Application which we log into using standard Individual User Accounts.

Depending upon the users login, they are then also logged into a web service after the Web Application login has been mapped to the required Web Service login. It is not a one to one mapped login, the user could select to access any one of a number of available web services.

i.e.

- Web App login JohnD is mapped to Web Service A using Employee login details;
- Web App login FredF is mapped to Web Service B using Maintainer login details;
- Web App login BarneyR is mapped to Web Service B using Visitor login details;

An administration module should allow the assignment of Web App login to Web Service login.

For Proof Of Concept we've embedded some Web service login details within the Web Application. This is obviously insecure and we need to store the Web Service login details securely somewhere, somehow, encrypted in SQL Server tables? encrypted in WebConfig?

What is the best way to securely store and retrieve the mapped login details? or a better way to perform this 2 step login logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never store login details in reversible format (can be fully decrypted).

If the login details is reversible by the server then hackers will be able to do the same to retrieve everyone's login information upon successfully stealing the DB.

Login information for your own site should be stored with one way hash + salted. There is no reason why you would use a lower level security for 3rd party sites.

OAuth with access rights should be the answer to your question since it doesn't require users to give your site full access to the 3rd party site. After your site gets compromised the 3rd party site's login info won't be effected at all. Users can break the link to prevent further damage to their 3rd party site's account without having to wait for admin actions.

Comment: I wouldn't say *never*. More like *rarely*. OAuth is certainly a good way around this issue, but sometimes 3rd parties don't provide that. There are some cases where storing the data encrypted may be your only option, though it should be a last resort and it's a good idea to warn users of the risks of storing that information in your system.

Comment: I believe that WSO2 can be used for authentication by the web service provider, which I will investigate further; the slight twist is that we provide the login details for the web services through a different internal 'department'. So we kind of own all the logins and I was hoping to keep this as simple as possible due to the 'as ever' short delivery time... but my better self tells me to go the WSO2 / OAuth route... just got to sell it to the powers that be.